# What is the benefit of having merge-commit if we follow a process of squashing commits before merging into main

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Say we have a repo **R** with ***develop*** as the branch where all folks merge their feature branches.
Now if I am developing a feature which has 3 commits *a,b,c* and before merging into ***develop***, our company follows a process of squashing those commits into single commit say *a*, then is there any benefit of having a separate **merge-commit** in ***develop*** branch when we actually merge, as it is creating 2 separate commits for a single feature.

Comment: Why would you not want merge commits? Do you not have to go look in the history of your main branch to identify what merged when by using something like gitk?

Comment: @KausUntwale I don't think the question is about *wanting* merge commits or not. Instead it's about if the merge commit has value in this specific scenario. In this case the `--first-parent` diff would be identical to the commits themselves.

Comment: Ultimately this winds up just being an opinion: as @TTT notes / answers, there's little if any real benefit (the one I can see is those extra date stamps) to making merge bubbles when every merge just has the one commit in it, but some people's *opinion* of Proper Use of Git includes making merge bubbles. I don't have a strong opinion one way or the other myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you **could** do a fast forward merge, and if **all** of your merges contain **exactly one commit**, then there really isn't a benefit to using `--no-ff` (as proposed by Git Flow) to force a merge commit, since there is no information gained, with the exception of the author, date, and text of the merge commit message. In theory, any additional information in the merge commit could be appended to the single commit message details if desired (e.g. "... PR completed by John Doe on 2021-09-28 13:30:01).

Extrapolating on this, there's an argument to be made that you could use a fast-forward merge anytime there is exactly 1 commit, and then force a merge commit anytime there is more than 1 commit. This however might make the `--first-parent` view more varied, as it would potentially be mixing developer written messages with merge commit messages, (though perhaps that could be adjusted by your SCM tool). I work in a repo that uses Git Flow where the majority of PRs have just one commit, but I still prefer the `--no-ff` for all merges, just for consistency of knowing all the PR information is always in the merge commit.

My personal preference is not to force a squash in the first place, since separate commits have value (if the developers take the time to make them valuable). However, if we were doing a squash, I think I might lean towards a completely linear graph over forcing a tiny merge bubble every time, *if* the PR info could be added to the details of the commit message.

Side Note: if you're using Git Flow, I might still prefer to force merge commits when merging protected branches back and forth (`release` into `main`, `main` into `develop`, etc) so you can know *when* those branches were updated. Particularly the `main` branch, which may represent releases into production.

Answer (score 0):

What does company say about the process ? Why not ask them directly ?

One benefit is that your merge-commit might be urgently reverted with git-revert if something goes wrong. or even just :

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

In that case your commit is gone, with all your work. In the meantime you might be asked to make a fix of things that caused the problem that initiated the revert. So you would simply checkout your feature branch, make the fix and merge again. So, having separate commits, just makes it a bit cleaner and gives a bit more possibilities to play around with git when things get nasty.

As the squash commit itself, it might be done for the sake of simpler review and has nothing to do with the final merge-commit.

Maintaining git on daily bases at my company, I can say the more information is in git the easier it is to deal with some hard situations that happen on regular basis.

Comment: Note this question is not asking about the value of merge commits in general. I'm not following your explanation of how the merge commit has a benefit over the commit, based on *this specific question's scenario*. For example, "urgently" reverting a merge commit isn't any easier than reverting one commit. In fact, arguably it's the teeniest bit harder since you have to type about 5 more characters. :D

Comment: Two commits are better than the 1,because one can be reverted from develop branch and the feature branch will still contain all the work under the second commit. Companies usually develop a workflow and follow specific processes, so that it is easier for them to clean up a mass when it happens and strict processes also produce less errors in general.There might be no real benefits at all in having such processes as git allows to deal with all kind of crap people end up with while doing git, however it is easier when people follow one path in general.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. If you didn't delete the feature branch after merging into `develop`, it's going to still be there for you to work on regardless of whether you revert the merge commit, or the commit, right? ;)